# Tag 'graphs' - two distinct usages - what to do?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that the tag 'graphs' is used at least twofold:

- for questions involving graphs in the sense of nodes and links
- for questions where 'graphs' means in fact 'charts'

For me, this is not good.

What do you think?

Answer (score 7):

I agree that those are two distinct usages and should not share one tag. `graphs` implies your first bullet point, to me. The second one should be tagged `charts` or `visualization` or `plots` or something. Feel free to propose tag edits where you see this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is from 3.5 years ago, but I just proposed a entry for the graphs tag.

They are a minority, but there are quite a few questions that should be re-tagged visualization.

Comment: What (if anything) should be the distinction between this clarified [tag:graphs] and [tag:social-network-analysis]?  The latter sounds more specific, but its current tag wiki is not.

Comment: @BenReiniger Do you think social network analysis should start by saying it is a type of graph analysis? Otherwise, they both seem fine to me: someone asking a question about social networks is likely to get the right tag.